# How can I load a static page to a second address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two production rails apps at `http://www.firstapp.com` and `https://www.secondapp.com`

I want to create a new static page, `https://www.secondapp.com/static_pages/about`, and I want its content to reflect what already exists at `http://www.firstapp.com/static_pages/about`.

Is there an easy way for me to do this? I don't want to have to reconstruct a page I've already created in `firstapp`. Also, I would prefer to be able to dynamically update the about page in `secondapp` just by editing the corresponding page in `firstapp`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the whole static page to be identical, then this is not a rails issue, that is what redirects are for. set a rule in your webserver configuration to point 
`https://www.secondapp.com/static_pages/about` to `http://www.firstapp.com/static_pages/about`

Comment: Hi @Viktor, do you have an idea of how I can go about doing this? I set up both domains through DNSimple and have them running on Heroku. They have options related to the DNS setup, but this doesn't seem to address redirecting specific subdirectory pages.